# Sensu mailer not respecting occurrences setting

Tags: sensu

I'm using the `sensu-mailer` handler to send email alerts. It works fine, expect for the fact that I cannot get it to send emails at every occurrence. No matter what value for `occurrences` I give, it doesn't change

```
# config

"ping_website": {
      "notification": "getpostman.com HTTP port 80",
      "command": "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-http.rb -u <url>",
      "subscribers": [ "base" ],
      "standalone": true,
      "interval": 60,
      "occurrences": 1,
      "handlers": ["default", "mailer"]
    }

# log

{"timestamp":"2015-03-01T05:40:44.233827+0000","level":"info","message":"handler output","handler":{"type":"pipe","command":"ruby /etc/sensu/handlers/mailer.rb","name":"mailer"},"output":"only handling every 30 occurrences: localhost/ping_website\n"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to set `refresh` to a different value. Since the default value is 1800 seconds, another alert won't be sent for another 30 consecutive occurrences of the error. Setting `refresh` to a lower number fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue with my custom handler, but later when double check my check config file I was missing these values. @elssar Thanks.

```
  "notification_occurrences": 1, 
    "refresh": 180, 
    "occurrences": 2,
```

While I check handler somethingnd some thing like

```
only handling every 10 occurrences
```

Then I trigger handler manually with 10 occurrences so then its work.
Also some help form documentation.
Already answered but may help someone with a custom handler.
https://docs.sensu.io/sensu-core/1.2/reference/events/#event-attributes

[https://docs.sensu.io/sensu-enterprise/2.8/filters/handle-when/#handlewhen-attributes](https://docs.sensu.io/sensu-enterprise/2.8/filters/handle-when/#handlewhen-attributeshttps://docs.sensu.io/sensu-enterprise/2.8/filters/handle-when/#handlewhen-attributes)